# how to get specific column from REG QUERY?

Tags: cmd, registry

```
c:>REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
  XSENZ REG_SZ C:\Windows\syswow64\XSENZ.EXE
  Persistence REG_SZ C:\windows\system32\igfxpers.exe
  IntelliPoint REG_SZ "c:\Program Files\Microsoft IntelliPoint\ipoint.exe"
  IgfxTray REG_SZ C:\windows\system32\igfxtray.exe
  HotKeysCmds REG_SZ C:\windows\system32\hkcmd.exe
```

I want to get only first column. Can anyone suggest an answer?

Comment: "The first column." What does that mean to you? It means nothing to me. What output do you want - exemplify from the supplied result, since the result on my machine is bound to be different from the data on yours.

Comment: I want just name of startup program

Comment: example:XSENZ,Persistence,IntelliPoint ...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run') do @echo %%a|find /v "\"
```

should work for you. If you are running directly from the prompt, reduce `%%` to `%`

Comment: Just commenting here that it truncates the names when they have spaces in them, to just the first term.